# Python - what is the correct way to copy an object's attributes over to another?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have two classes. They're almost identical, except for 2 attributes. I need to copy all the attributes over from one to the other, and I'm just wondering **if there is a pattern** or best practice, **or** if I should just basically do:

```
spam.attribute_one = foo.attribute_one
spam.attribute_two = foo.attribute_two
```

... and so on.

Comment: why don't you use inheritance ?

Comment: @Tumbleweed - They're ORM classes. One is for transaction record keeping in the database, and they have such different uses, methods, etc that it's just more work in the long run to try to use inheritance (not to mention I plan to clean out the one, and keep the other permanently).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The code you give is correct and safe, avoiding "accidentally" binding attributes that should *not* be bound.  If you favor automation over safety and correctness, though, you *could* use something like...:

```
def blindcopy(objfrom, objto):
    for n, v in inspect.getmembers(objfrom):
        setattr(objto, n, v);
```

However, I would not recommend it (for the reasons implied by the first para;-).  OTOH, if you know the names of the attributes you want to copy, the following is just fine:

```
def copysome(objfrom, objto, names):
    for n in names:
        if hasattr(objfrom, n):
            v = getattr(objfrom, n)
            setattr(objto, n, v);
```

If you do this kind of thing often, having this code *once* in a "utilities" module can be a definite win for you!

Comment: thanks yet again. I kind of like your second method, but I'll stick with your advice and do it the correct and safe way. Having a tuple of field names won't spare me much code-space/cleanliness anyways.

Comment: the for-loop in the blindcopy-function misses the in-operator.

Answer (score 3):

If they're that similar, and need to change state, it sounds like you really have instances of one class, and a `mode` or similar attribute that determines how it behaves. Objects shouldn't morph from one object to another, similar but separate object, very often at all.

Comment: Sort of, but their use is different enough to warrant two classes. Also, their ORM classes, and one is for record keeping. The other will be purged periodically.

Answer (score 0):

I used dictionary comprehension to iterate through the items and call `setattr()` for another object.

```
{k: setattr(object_to, k, v) for k, v in object_from.dict().items()}
```

Since I don't need any new `dict`, I have not assigned the return value to any variable.

Another way I tried is by using map()

```
dict(
    map(lambda item: (item[0], setattr(object_to, item[0], item[1])
                      ),
        object_from.dict().items()
        )
)
```

This might save a lot of loop iteration time.