# How to determine if a Python class attribute is read only/writeable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use `inspect.getmembers()` to list all the writeable attributes of a class. Is there a way to query if a class attribute is readonly or writeable?

Edit: I'm using the first solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3818861/2746401 and get an error when trying to copy read-only attributes (e.g. `__doc__`). I want to filter our these read-only properties and only copy the writeable ones

Comment: What are you going to do with that information? What does it mean to you to be read only or writable (are you talking about descriptors like `@property`? What about interference via `__getattr[ibute]__`/`__setattr__`?)

Comment: I'm using the first solution from http://stackoverflow.com/a/3818861/2746401 and get an error when read-only attributes (e.g. __doc__) are copied. I want to filer our these read-only properties and only copy the writeable ones.

Comment: Please [edit] to include the context in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Most names will be settable by default. The exceptions are the [*data descriptor objects*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) and classes that define the [`__setattr__` hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__).

A data descriptor is any attribute of the class that has a [`__get__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) and at least either a [`__set__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set__) or a [`__delete__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delete__) method. These methods are used when you try to set or delete the attribute on an *instance* of the class.

Data descriptors with a `__set__` method **may** not be writeable, and it'll depend on the exact descriptor implementation what they'll allow. A [`property` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) is such a data descriptor; if the `property` has a `fset` attribute set to `None` it won't be writeable. If `property().fset` is not set to `None` but to a callable, then that callable determines if the attribute is writeable.

In addition, any data descriptor with only a `__delete__` method can't be written either, the lack of a `__set__` method results in a `AttributeError` when you try to set the attribute name on the instance.

A `__setattr__` hook intercepts all attribute setting, and can prevent any such action to fail. There is a corresponding `__delattr__` hook too, which matters if you want to count deleting attributes as writing.

In other words, this is *really hard to determine*, not in a generic way, once descriptors or a `__setattr__` hook are involved.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the necromancer.

If `AttributeError` is thrown on attempting to write to a read-only attribute, as should happen, you catch:

```py
def isro(o,attr):

  v=getattr(o,attr);

  try:
    setattr(o,attr,v);
    return False;

  except AttributeError:
    return True;
```

^Here we attempt to write with the already existing value, assumed to be valid for attr. If it fails, it's read only. Else it's not.

A simplistic test, to which there might be edge cases. Feel free to point them out if you know them.

I do not think this check would be fast if done in bulk, however; haven't tested. But my gut says filter out the read-only attributes in such cases:

```py
filtered=[
  attr for attr in attr_list
  if not isro(o,attr)
];
```

You run the check once per attribute, as opposed to per attribute for each object: *should* be the more performant approach is what my senses tell me. What remains then is walking through the filtered list of attributes.

Again, feel free to point out anything missing. This is just the quick-n-dirty I applied to solve this issue for myself.

Ta-ta.